# How to show that sampling from correlated fraction PDFs does not reproduce correlations?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, correlation

Let's assume that we have $N$ layers over which a quantity X is distributed, i.e. $X = \sum_{i=1}^{N} X_i$ for each 'data point'. Now, we know how the Probability Density Function $f(X)$ of the overall quantity as well as the Probability Denity Function of the fraction in each layer $g(X_i^{\mathrm{frac}})$ with $X_i^{\mathrm{frac}}=\frac{X_i}{X}$ look. We also know that the correlations of $X_i$ are not zero, i.e. $\rho(X_i, X_j) \neq 0$. How can I concisely show that if I would just sample data from the fraction PDFs $g(X_i^{\mathrm{frac}})$ and the total PDF $f(X)$ with the constrain of the fractions always summing up to $X$, it would not be possible to reproduce the original correlations. Hope this was clear!

Comment: This is not fully clear. When you sample data from the fraction PDFs are your samples for $i$ and $j$ independent ? If yes this answers the question. If no: how exactly do you sample those data ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I guess if I would sample data independently from the PDFs they would not be correlated by definition? (and I would also not be sure how to make sure that the fractions always add to one in that case) Let me re-phrase the question then: Is there a way to sample from the fraction PDFs such that the samples are not indepenent and the correlations are preserved?

Comment: To understand what the problem is simplify it as follows: the $X_i$ are known to be pairwise correlated but all standard normal. Now sample $N$ independent standard normals $Y_i$. It is a *no brainer* that you won't reproduce the $X_i$'s correlations.

Comment: Fair, what about the other question? Is there a way to sample from the fraction PDFs such that the samples are not indepenent and the correlations are preserved? :)

Comment: To get some grip on that I would probably look at $N=2$ and fire up some simulation in python.

Comment: I was more looking for some fundamental thoughts on this